# JavaFX children edit without external css files

Tags: java, css, javafx, external, stylesheet

I am trying to edit a design of the ProgressIndicator.

In code i can set the style, but it seems that I can't reach the children such as

.progress .
I know i can change the style using custom css stylesheet but is there a way to do this without external files?

I am trying to change the color of the #progress child.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout of most controls are done through their skin.

This should work, provided the scene graph is already built (lookup can run).

```
StackPane progress = (StackPane) progressIndicator.getSkin().lookup(".progress");
progress.setStyle("mystyle");
```